# Getting resultcode -1 from startActivityforResult , what -1 means

Tags: android, android-activity

In an android activity if resultcode returned is -1 , what does it mean in the following code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resultCode of -1 maps to [Activity.RESULT_OK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK), so your activity is returning success.